# how to use onload event in angular 2 with dynamically inserted image source

Tags: angular, onload

I want to set certain flags when image is downloaded. I tried using onload event on image tag and call function. With what I implemented below  I am getting error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: imageLoaded is not
>   defined
>       at HTMLImageElement.onload

component.html:

```
 <img onload='imageLoaded()' class='doc-img' [src]='imageUrl'>
```

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.getDocumentImage()
}

getDocumentImage()
{
     this.imageUrl= 
this.domSanitizerService.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`${API.document}/{documentId}`);
}

imageLoaded(){
    alert("image loaded");
}
```

Need some article reference or help in debugging this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img (load)='imageLoaded()' class='doc-img' [src]='imageUrl'>
```